# D3 collapsible trees without flare.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to integrate a collapsible tree with a visualization tool :

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

Can someone please tell me how to make this code run without a flare.json file. I have the data in json format and I need to use that json output to make this code run. The code I have that converts a string into a json format is as follows:

```
<html>

<body>

<script>
//example dat

var str = "Charles Johnson\t4184\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams\t8385\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig\t428\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling\t1091\nCharles Johnson-Donald Williams-Daniel Fertig-Lino Walling-Jim Cooke\t318";
var lines = str.split("\n");

var name_ = lines[0].split("\t")[0];
var val_ = lines[0].split("\t")[1];
//alert(val_);
var obj = {name:     name_,
           children: [],
           value:    val_};
//process all lines
for (var i=1;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var addr = lines[i].split("\t")[0].split("-");
  var val = lines[i].split("\t")[1];
  //alert(val);
  var local_obj  = obj;
  var recursive_obj;
  //alert(addr.length);
  for (var j=1;j<addr.length;j++) {
    recursive_obj = null;
    for (var k=0;k<local_obj.children.length;k++) {   //Doest get used for first instance
      if (local_obj.children[k].name==addr[j]) {
        recursive_obj=local_obj.children[k];
      }
    }
    if (recursive_obj==null) {
      recursive_obj = {name:     addr[j],
                       children: [],
                       value:    null
                      };
      local_obj.children.push(recursive_obj);
    }   
    local_obj=recursive_obj;

  }
  recursive_obj.value=val;
}

//print a json result
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
</script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

This code converts the string into Json Format. Can someone please help me out in using this code instead of

```
treeJSON = d3.json("flare.json", function(error, treeData){}
```

and making the collapsible tree run. I would be very grateful if someone can assist me with this. Thank you :)

Best Regards
Mohd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="try.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="tree-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your data is formatted to look like the data in `flare.json`, just use it as `data` in that code and take out the `d3.json` line.

Comment: Thank you @Lars...Can you please elaborate a little bit on that. The obj variable has the data in the valid json format. How do I go about it from thereon? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The whole code is inside 
   "treeJSON = d3.json("flare.json", function(error, treeData) "
function so I was confused where would I have to make the changes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have `obj`, which is already an object, similar to what `treeData` needs to be inside the callback to the `d3.json` function. You can take everything out of that function, converting from this:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, treeData){
  //Do some stuff with treeData
})
```

to this:

```
var treeData = obj;
//Do some stuff with treeData;
```

Working fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6qGJ/1/)

Comment: Thank you Lars I'll try that out. So it's just that one line of code changing :o ?

Comment: Ok so making that change doesnt display anything :|....I basically copied everything inside the
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, treeData){}
 And pasted it below  var treeData = obj;
Is there more that I have to do?

Comment: There shouldn't be, if you have your html set up right. I added a fiddle of the working code to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @ckersch... Strangely it's still coming out as blank :/...I am using a simple html file for the fiddle you sent which is attached below my question. Can you kindly tell me where I'm making a mistake..Thank you so  much for all the help btw :)

Comment: Not really sure without being able to see your code. I'd recommend debugging and see if you're getting any errors, then looking at the html and seeing what isn't getting rendered.

Comment: Thank you @ ckersch...I'll go ahead and do that...Thank you for all the assistance, appreciate it :)